# onLayout with Image - React Native

Tags: react-native

I have a problem with onLayout in Image:

I have a function to display the dimension.

```
measureView(event) {
   console.log(event.nativeEvent.layout.width);
   console.log(event.nativeEvent.layout.height);
}
```

This Works and shows me the dimension of the TouchableWithoutFeedback

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback
 style={styles.touchableWithoutFeedback}
 onLayout={(event) => this.measureView(event)}>
     <Image style={styles.image} 
     source={require("./../assets/images/photo_1.jpg")}/>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

But With the onLayout in the Image, i got nothing, just undefined.

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback
 style={styles.touchableWithoutFeedback}>
     <Image style={styles.image} 
     source={require("./../assets/images/photo_1.jpg")}
     onLayout={(event) => this.measureView(event)}/>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

Do you have an Idea why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had this problem recently as well.  It looks like the `<Image />` component mounts before the actual image gets loaded into the container.  You probably want to instead use the `onLoad` property of `<Image />`.  Once you do that you can pretty much proceed as normal...

```
<Image
  onLoad={event => { console.log(event.nativeEvent.source); }}
  source={require("./../assets/images/photo_1.jpg")}
  style={styles.image}
/>

// Would log { height: 123, url: 'somestring', width: 123 }
```

Keep in mind that may or may not only work for static resources.  I'm not 100% that network images provide a size through that function.

Good luck! :)

Comment: Endeed, I have changed completely my code for network images. But your answer is right!

Comment: Just a warning. If the loaded image is 'too big' (about 2048 px) images will be automaticaly downsampled. This happens to avoid crash on some devices that can't handle large bitmaps. It took me some time to understand why ImageManipulator.manipulateAsync wasn't working properly. By the way, Image.getSize has the same issue.

More info: 
[1] https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/22145
[2] https://github.com/facebook/fresco/issues/2236#issuecomment-438693057